# Toyota K114 WD Differential

Tags: toyota, cvt-transmission, harrier

I am getting this an issue with Toyota Harrier 2014 with 2WD CVT differential on the Tranmission. It is keeping a noise when pulling off that goes away with higher RPM.

The CVT diff was removed and is very stiff. Is this normal?

Video: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/W4_-SDxvdZI

Need some help.

Thanks.